# MVC Optional Parameter Default Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, optional-parameters

I have the following MVC Action:

```
[ActionName("order-brochure")]
public ActionResult OrderBrochure(int brochureId, bool isModal = true)
{
    return View(HomeModelBuilder.BuildOrderBrochureModel(brochureId, isModal, false));
}
```

Where `isModal` is an optional parameter

Is there any other way to set the default for this other than using `bool isModal = true` within the method as my company uses code analysis and this fails giving a **CA1026: default parameters shouldn't be used**

However, I can't override the method as you can't have two actions with the same name as you'll get an error along the following lines:

```
The current request for action 'order-brochure' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods: 
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult OrderBrochureModal(Int32, Boolean) on type MarshallsCoUkCommercial.Website.Controllers.HomeController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult OrderBrochure(Int32) on type MarshallsCoUkCommercial.Website.Controllers.HomeController
```

And if I use

```
public ActionResult OrderBrochure(int brochureId, bool isModal)
```

Setting `isModal` to `UrlParameter.Optional`

I can't test to see if `isModal` is null as it will always be set to false

Comment: What about `public ActionResult OrderBrochure(int brochureId, bool? isModal)`? Now you _can_ test it to see if it's `null`.

Comment: Weird I tried it as a nullable bool before and it just crashed, just tried it again and it now works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this rule is outdated and should not be applied to C# 4.0 and above. See [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ba3bb8d-3233-4cda-a1c3-03235219d636/c-4-and-ca1026-default-parameters-should-not-be-used?forum=vstscode) for similar question.

I would say just disable this rule, as it makes no sense in MVC4.

However, suppressing the rule might not be compliant with your company rules, then you'd have to work around that. (These rules are silly, when you have to hack around some outdated crap like that!)

One of the options is to have a custom rule for the every case like that: specify default value for optional param. (Sorry, can't find implementation for that quickly)

Or, as already suggested go with nullable boolean

```
public ActionResult OrderBrochure(int brochureId, bool? isModal)
```

and then in your method check for null on `isModel`.

Comment: I thought it made no sense with MVC4, I've just sent an email to my boss asking him to disable it!  Thanks